# Single quantum particle in beam splitter, with different systems located in each channel

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, quantum-entanglement

Suppose a quantum mechanical particle enters a beam-splitter, which sends its wave packets into two mutually orthogonal channels, $C_a$ and $C_b$. Suppose that $C_a$ also contains System A, with observable $|\Psi_A\rangle$, with which the particle's (in general, different) observable $|\Psi_P\rangle$ interacts, via Hamiltonian $H_{AP}$. $C_b$ does not contain system A, nor any other system (just free space).

Without System A, once within the beam splitter, we could use the simple description:

\begin{equation} |\Psi\rangle =   (|C_a\rangle + |C_b\rangle)  /  \sqrt 2 \end{equation}

With System A located in $C_a$, after the particle enters the beam splitter, the wave function of the composite system evolves to:

\begin{equation}|\Psi\rangle_{t = t_{A+\tau}} = \exp \left( -i\int^{t_{A+\tau}}_{t_A} H_{AP} \mathrm{d}t \right)|\Psi_{A_i}\rangle|\Psi_{P_i}\rangle |C_a\rangle   +   |\Psi_{A_i}\rangle|\Psi_{P_i}\rangle |C_b\rangle \end{equation}

where the notation "$|\alpha\rangle |\beta\rangle$" represents the tensor product of $|\alpha\rangle$ and $ |\beta\rangle$. $|\Psi_{A_i}\rangle$ is the initial state of System A's observable before interacting with the particle, $|\Psi_{P_i}\rangle$ is the initial state of the particle's observable before interacting with System A, $t_A$ is the time when the particle begins interacting with System A, and $t_{A+\tau}$ is when the particle stops interacting with System A. Normalization is suppressed for simplicity.

In the second equation, the $C_a$ term contains a Hamiltonian that associates specific states of the particle with specific states of System A (entanglement of the particle with system A). The $C_b$ term contains the "null" Hamiltonian, which associates each state of the particle with all states of System A (for all intents and purposes, no entanglement of the particle with System A). Further, the second equation implies that if both channels were later recombined, there would be no interference between their components of the wave function of the particle.

Does the above description sound correct?

Comment: Have a look at this experiment http://phys.org/news/2011-01-which-way-detector-mystery-double-slit.html. It says that once the situation changes for slit A with a filter the solution changes, the filter at the slit becoming a source for the photons that interact with it, destroying the coherence. Your inclusion of systemA at Ca does something similar. You cannot have one wavefunction imo, you will need a density matrix formalism.

Comment: @anna_v:  After time $t_{A+\tau}$, I think that the particle alone (not including system A), will need to be described by a reduced density matrix (of the composite density matrix) and the particle will be in a mixed state. Is that what you mean?

Comment: yes , at least that is what the link I gave implies. The solution which will give the probability of finding the particle in a or b will be mixed. the particle is whole each time it is measured

Comment: @anna v: But I think that the composite system, of the particle and system A, will have a wave function in a pure state, as I described above, where its two terms, for the two different channels, have different interaction Hamiltonians for how the particle and system A interact.

Comment: This paper helps motivate my thinking: http://quantum.phys.cmu.edu/CQT/chaps/cqt18.pdf

Comment: I think when you have two different hamiltonians coherence is lost. I hope a theoretically inclined contributor will answer your question. The above is just my experimentalist's opinion.

Comment: @anna v: I definately agree coherence should be lost. The point I hope to get confirmation on is the use of two different Hamiltonians. Thank you dor your responses!

Comment: This is mostly fine although you have neglected the free evolution of the particle and auxiliary system. In general your propagator should be (schematically) $U(t) =T\exp (\int H_{AP}(t))$, where $T$ is time-ordering and $H_{AP}(t)$ is the interaction Hamiltonian in the interaction-picture representation. Then you find the interference fringe visibility will be proportional to $\langle \Psi_{A_i}\lvert \langle \Psi_{P_i} \rvert  U(t) \lvert \Psi_{P_i}\rangle \lvert \Psi_{A_i} \rangle$. So how much the coherence is lost depends on the interaction $H_{AP}$.

Comment: Note that your assumption is essentially that the full interaction Hamiltonian is $H_{AP} \otimes \lvert C_a\rangle \langle C_a\rvert$, i.e. the interaction energy vanishes in state $\lvert C_b\rangle$.

Comment: @Mark Mitchison: My assumption is that since System A is physically only in channel Ca, with no influence of it in Cb, then there is no interaction of System A with the particle in Cb.

Comment: @David That's what I just said in a slightly more formal way. Such a scenario corresponds precisely to the interaction I wrote down above. If you work through the calculation you will see that this leads to your idea of "two different Hamiltonians". Actually there is just one Hamiltonian but it depends on the states $C_{a/b}$.

Comment: @Mark Mitchison: Above, you referred to the expectation value of the time evolution operator (⟨ΨPi∣U(t)∣ΨPi⟩). Could you please provide a reference that explains the meaning of that? I can't seem to google this kind of expectation value. Thanks, David

Comment: @David It's a result of decoherence theory. I'll write up an answer soon which should clarify where it comes from.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's write the full Hamiltonian of the problem as
$$ H = H_A + H_P + H_C + V,$$
where $H_A + H_P + H_C$ are the local Hamiltonians of $A$, $P$ and $C$, and their interaction is $V$. If you want the interaction to take place in arm $a$ of the interferometer, the interaction should be of the form
$$ V = H_{AP} \otimes \lvert C_a \rangle \langle C_a\rvert.$$
For an interferometer, we should have that $\lvert C_{a/b}\rangle$ are eigenstates of $H_C$, which means that $[V,H_C] = 0$. Moving to an interaction picture generated by $H_0 = H_A + H_P + H_C$, the time evolution operator is 
\begin{align} U(t) = T \exp \left ( \int_0^t\mathrm{d}s \,V(s) \right) & = T \exp \left ( \int_0^t\mathrm{d}s \,H_{AP}(s)\otimes \lvert C_a \rangle \langle C_a\rvert \right),
\end{align}
where $V(s)$, $H_{AP}(s)$ are interaction-picture operators, e.g. $V(t) = \mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}H_0t}V\mathrm{e}^{-\mathrm{i}H_0t}$.

Now compute the evolution of the quantum state in the interaction picture
\begin{align} 
\lvert \Psi(t)\rangle & =  U(t)\lvert \Psi(0)\rangle \\ &= U(t)\lvert \Psi_{A_i}\rangle \lvert \Psi_{P_i}\rangle \left[ \lvert C_a \rangle + \lvert C_b \rangle \right] \\
& = T \exp \left ( \int_0^t\mathrm{d}s \,H_{AP}(s) \right)\lvert \Psi_{A_i}\rangle \lvert \Psi_{P_i}\rangle\lvert C_a \rangle + \lvert \Psi_{A_i}\rangle \lvert \Psi_{P_i}\rangle\lvert C_b \rangle,
\end{align}
where I have neglected an overall normalisation factor.

Interference indicates the presence of coherence between the path states $\lvert C_{a/b}\rangle$. In other words, if the path states are recombined at a second beam splitter (or some other kind of interference experiment) the output measures the matrix element* $\langle C_a \lvert \rho_C \rvert C_b\rangle$, where $\rho_C$ is the reduced density matrix corresponding to the path degrees of freedom, i.e.
$$ \rho_C(t) = \mathrm{Tr}_{AP} \left \lbrace\lvert \Psi(t) \rangle \langle \Psi(t)\rvert \right\rbrace,$$
where $\mathrm{Tr}_{AP}$ means the partial trace over the Hilbert space of $A$ and $P$.

Putting everything together, we obtain
$$\langle C_a \lvert \rho_C(t) \rvert C_b\rangle = \langle \Psi_{P_i}\rvert \langle \Psi_{A_i}\rvert T \exp \left ( \int_0^t\mathrm{d}s \,H_{AP}(s) \right)\lvert \Psi_{A_i}\rangle \lvert \Psi_{P_i}\rangle. $$
The magnitude of this expression is a real number between 0 and 1 giving the interference visibility (0 means no interference, 1 means maximum interference). Note that there is also a phase which affects the result of the interference experiment. For example, in a [Mach-Zehnder interferometer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mach%E2%80%93Zehnder_interferometer), the phase determines which output port the particle (photon) will be detected. If you instead are doing a [double-slit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-slit_experiment) type experiment, the phase determines the position of the interference maxima on the detecting screen.

Depending on the kind of interaction $H_{AP}$, you could get anything from a simple phase shift to a complete loss of interference. Generally speaking, if the states $\lvert \Psi_{P_i/A_i}\rangle$ are eigenstates of $H_{AP}(t)$ at all times, then you just get a phase shift. However, if the interaction leads to transitions to different states of $P,A$, then the interference will be partially or completely destroyed.

---

*Notice that $\langle C_a \lvert \rho_C \rvert C_b\rangle$ is complex and therefore cannot be written as the expectation value of a Hermitian operator. Thus it is not strictly speaking a quantum mechanical observable. A given interferometer set-up can only measure either the real or the imaginary part of $\langle C_a \lvert \rho_C \rvert C_b\rangle$. (Or to be more precise, it can measure only one of the two real numbers needed to specify a single complex number: it might instead measure the magnitude or the phase, for example).

Comment: Mark Mitchison: (1) of (2): I think $$ \langle \Psi_{P_i}\rvert \langle \Psi_{A_i}\rvert U(t) \lvert \Psi_{A_i}\rangle \lvert \Psi_{P_i}\rangle $$ could also be derived by noticing that $$\lvert \Psi_{A_i}\rangle \lvert \Psi_{P_i}\rangle $$ is the initial state vector of the composite system of system A and the particle (before interaction), $$U(t) \lvert \Psi_{A_i}\rangle \lvert \Psi_{P_i}\rangle $$  is the state vector of the composite system at time t (sometime after interaction).

Comment: (2) of (2): So, $$ \langle \Psi_{P_i}\rvert \langle \Psi_{A_i}\rvert U(t) \lvert \Psi_{A_i}\rangle \lvert \Psi_{P_i}\rangle $$ is a measure of how different the composite system is after interaction, from what it was before the interaction. If there is no difference, the value of the inner product is 1 and we would expect maximum interference. if the value is zero, then those vectors have no overlap and so no interference. Does that seem like another way to think of it?

Comment: What is interesting about this is that a quantum particle's wave function can live out one scenario in channel a, even causing back-action to System A there, but live out a totally different scenario in channel b. If the particle is detected in channel b, then the interaction with system A, and subsequent back-action on system A is nullified. Of course, that is only in the, perhaps, rare case where a wave function is split into two non-zero packets, each going in a different direction and interacting with different highly localized things. It kind of captures my imagination.

Comment: @David Indeed, the visibility is just given by the overlap between the initial and final states of A and P. I agree, interferometry is a very rich and fascinating subject!

Comment: @ Mark Mitchison:  One last thing, I am not sure how derived:  \begin{align}U(t)\lvert \Psi_{A_i}\rangle \lvert \Psi_{P_i}\rangle \left[ \lvert C_a \rangle + \lvert C_b \rangle \right]  = T \exp \left ( \int_0^t\mathrm{d}s \,H_{AP}(s) \right)\lvert \Psi_{A_i}\rangle \lvert \Psi_{P_i}\rangle\lvert C_a \rangle + \lvert \Psi_{A_i}\rangle \lvert \Psi_{P_i}\rangle\lvert C_b \rangle,
\end{align}, given \begin{align} U(t) = T \exp \left ( \int_0^t\mathrm{d}s \,H_{AP}(s)\otimes \lvert C_a \rangle \langle C_a\rvert \right),
\end{align}

Comment: @ Mark Mitchison: (Above comment continued) For instance, I would think that the $|C_b \rangle$ term would get zeroed-out by the $\langle C_a|$,  in the exponential (exp), when the exponential is expanded as a taylor series. (Granted, I am no expert in the interaction picture; I am more familiar with the Schrodinger Picture, nor am I an expert in decoherence theory, which I think is where the formula for V came from.

Comment: @David The zeroth order term in the exponential is the identity operator 1. This is the only term which survives, the higher order terms are killed by the $\langle C_a \rvert C_b \rangle$.

Comment: @ Mark Mitchison: (1) of (2) $|C_a\rangle \langle C_a|$, from the exponential expressed as a taylor series, times $\Psi_{A_i}\rangle \lvert \Psi_{P_i}\rangle  \lvert C_a \rangle$ (or times $ \Psi_{A_i}\rangle \lvert \Psi_{P_i}\rangle \lvert C_b \rangle$) seems to need re-arranging.

Comment: @ Mark Mitchison: (2) of (2)  I  think you recognize the order of the vectors in $\Psi_{A_i}\rangle \lvert \Psi_{P_i}\rangle  \lvert C_a \rangle$ is arbitrary, so they are rearranged to $\lvert C_a \rangle \lvert \Psi_{A_i}\rangle \lvert \Psi_{P_i}\rangle$ so that we have $ \lvert C_a\rangle \langle C_a \lvert \lvert C_a \rangle|\Psi_{A_i}\rangle \lvert \Psi_{P_i}\rangle = |C_a \rangle |\Psi_{A_i}\rangle \lvert \Psi_{P_i} \rangle$ which can then be  re-arranged back to $\lvert \Psi_{A_i}\rangle \lvert \Psi_{P_i}\rangle \lvert C_a \rangle$. Else, there's algebraic Jiu Jitsu I'm missing. Thks

Comment: @ Mark Aitchison: Also, I think that the $\otimes$ (tensor product?) in the formula for V is from decoherence theory. But, does that not result in the following: \begin{align} 
\lvert \Psi(t)\rangle & = T \exp \left ( \int_0^t\mathrm{d}s \,H_{AP}(s) \right)\ \otimes \lvert \Psi_{A_i}\rangle \lvert \Psi_{P_i}\rangle\lvert C_a \rangle + \lvert \Psi_{A_i}\rangle \lvert \Psi_{P_i}\rangle\lvert C_b \rangle,
\end{align} I am not sure how the $\otimes$ goes away. Thanks again!

Comment: @David You seem to already understand the tensor product of vectors $\lvert \phi\rangle \otimes \lvert \psi \rangle$, a way of composing vectors living in different Hilbert spaces. The notation $A\otimes B$ means a tensor product of operators, meaning that the operators act on different Hilbert spaces. So, the notation $\otimes$ just means the following:
$$ (A\otimes B)  (\lvert \phi\rangle \otimes \lvert \psi \rangle) =  (A\lvert \phi\rangle) \otimes (B\lvert \psi \rangle) $$
Here (and in general) it is meaningless to write something like $U(t) \otimes \lvert \psi\rangle$.

Comment: @David BTW there was a bit of a typo in my answer which is corrected now, specifically the explicit expression for $\langle C_a \rvert \rho_C(t)\rvert C_b\rangle$.

Comment: @ Mark Mitchison: Got it! Thank you very much! Dave