# Loss of interference in single-photon Mach–Zehnder interferometer with detector in only one arm

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, interference, interferometry

I have read that if you have a Mach–Zehnder interferometer (doing a single-photon experiment) and put a non-destructive detector in only one of the two arms (connected to the first beam splitter), you lose interference when the wave packets of the photon are recombined at the second beam splitter.

I am trying to model this as a wave function, but am having trouble.

Suppose the interferometer consists of a first beam splitter, which the photon enters from its source, followed by arm $A_x$, heading along the cartesian $x$ direction, and arm $A_y$, heading along the cartesian $y$ direction. (so, the two arms are spatially orthogonal to each other). At the end of each arm is a mirror which directs the wave packets to a second beam splitter, which re-combines them. Also, suppose that somewhere in arm $A_x$ is a non-destructive detector. There is no detector, or anything else, in arm $A_y$

Neglecting the detector in $A_x$, right after the photon passes through the first beam splitter (time $t_1$), we would have

$|\Psi_{t_1}\rangle = (1/\sqrt 2) (|A_x\rangle + |A_y\rangle)$

That is, there is a 50% chance for the photon to be in either arm.

Taking the detector in $A_x$ into account, right after the photon passes through the first beam splitter (but before reaching the detector), we would have:

$|\Psi_{t_1}\rangle = |D_{off}\rangle (1/\sqrt 2) (|A_x\rangle + |A_y\rangle)$  where is the detector in its "off" state.

Next, at $t_2$, if the non-destructive detector registers the presence of the photon, then this should evolve to

$|\Psi_{t_2}\rangle = (1/\sqrt 2)(|D_{on}\rangle  |A_x\rangle + |D_{off}\rangle  |A_y\rangle $  where is the detector in its "on" state and the particle is in $|A_x\rangle)$.

Or, at $t_2$, if the non-destructive detector does not register the presence of the photon, and the particle is hence in $|A_y\rangle$, then this should evolve to

$|\Psi_{t_2}\rangle = (1/\sqrt 2)(|D_{off}\rangle  |A_x\rangle + |D_{off}\rangle  |A_y\rangle) =  |\Psi_{t_1}\rangle$  where is the detector remains in its "off" state.

If $\langle \Psi_{t_1}|\Psi_{t_2}\rangle = 0$, then after the second beam splitter, we would expect to see no interference.

However, I do not see how in both $t_2$ scenarios, described above, we end up with $\langle \Psi_{t_1}|\Psi_{t_2}\rangle = 0$

For instance, let $|A_y\rangle  = \left(\begin{array}{c}0\\1\end{array}\right) \quad |A_x\rangle  = \left(\begin{array}{c}1\\0\end{array}\right) \quad |D_{off}\rangle = \left(\begin{array}{c}0\\1\end{array}\right) \quad |D_{on}\rangle = \left(\begin{array}{c}1\\0\end{array}\right)$

Then $|\Psi_{t_1}\rangle = |D_{off}\rangle (1/\sqrt 2) (|A_x\rangle + |A_y\rangle) = \left(\begin{array}{c}0\\0\\1/\sqrt 2\\1/\sqrt 2\end{array}\right)$

$|\Psi_{t_2}\rangle = (1/\sqrt 2)(|D_{on}\rangle  |A_x\rangle + |D_{off}\rangle  |A_y\rangle = \left(\begin{array}{c}1/\sqrt 2\\0\\0\\1/\sqrt 2\end{array}\right) $

In that case, I do not get $\langle \Psi_{t_1}|\Psi_{t_2}\rangle = 0$.

Could you please tell me, where is my mistake? Thanks.

Comment: Interference is completely independent of the number of photons in the interferometer. A simple Mach-Zehnder interferometer shows interference in both arms even with detection, as the light leaves the interferometer anyway, whether detectors are present at the outputs or not. Putting a detector in one of the arms destroys the interference because there is no interferometer left... the technically interesting case that you are trying to model is not a simple Mach-Zehnder but a delayed-choice quantum eraser experiment, I suppose?

Comment: @ CuriousOne: Actually, I neglected to say that the detector is non-destructive. Also, maybe the single photon part is not relevant, but I am not sure what is wrong with my model of this, knowing that there should be no interference but not being able to get that result from my model. I would be very interested in seeing the correct model

Comment: The state of the system at $t_2$ is $|\Psi_{t_2}\rangle = (1/\sqrt 2)(|D_{on}\rangle  |A_x\rangle + |D_{off}\rangle  |A_y\rangle. $ Your second expression for $|\Psi_{t_2}\rangle $ is only true if the detector doesn't work (i.e. if its state is unchanged by the presence of the photon). The interference visibility, as defined in my other answer (http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/233190/single-quantum-particle-in-beam-splitter-with-different-systems-located-in-each), is $\langle D_{on}|D_{off}\rangle = 0$.

Comment: @ Mark Mitchison: In that answer (to the other post), you wrote that the amount of interference depends on $$\langle C_a \lvert \rho_C(t) \rvert C_b\rangle = \langle \Psi_{P_i}\rvert \langle \Psi_{A_i}\rvert T \exp \left ( \int_0^t\mathrm{d}s \,H_{AP}(s) \right)\lvert \Psi_{A_i}\rangle \lvert \Psi_{P_i}\rangle $$ which seems to me to be equivalent to $\langle\Psi_{t_1}|\Psi_{t_2}\rangle$ in this question. (The detector is non-destructive, if that matters here.)

Comment: @David No, in your other question you assumed the existence of an auxiliary system $A$ which does not appear here. The correct expression is $\langle \Psi_{P_i}\rvert T \exp \left (\int_0^t\mathrm{d}s\, H(s)\right) \lvert \Psi_{P_i}\rangle$, with $P$ the detector system and $H$ a Hamiltonian that switches the detector on. Given that here $\lvert \Psi_{P_i}\rangle  = \lvert D_{off}\rangle$, in the end this reduces to $\langle D_{off}\lvert D_{on}\rangle = 0$.

Comment: @ Mark Aitchison Thank you for the corrections. Got it.

Comment: I see... that makes more sense now. The single photon part is not relevant, but it does help to think about it. Just wanted to make sure it doesn't get stuck in someone's mind. One of the cool things about QM, after all, is that the total particle number doesn't matter for interference.

Comment: @ Mark Mitchison: If $[M]$ is an operator (in the form of a matrix) such that $[M]|D_{off}\rangle = |D_{on}\rangle$, then is the unitary time evolution operator that multiplies $\Psi{t_1}\rangle$ going to be:  $\exp\bigg( \int^{\infty}_{-\infty} ln([M])\delta(t) \mathrm{d}t \otimes |A_x \rangle \langle A_x|\bigg) = \exp\bigg( ln([M]) \otimes |A_x \rangle \langle A_x|\bigg)$?

Comment: @Mark Mitchison: Also, I think that  I think that $$[M] =  \left( \begin{array}{ccc}
0 & 1 \\
1 & 0 \\
 \end{array} \right)$$ if $|D_{on}\rangle = \left( \begin{array}{ccc}
1 \\
 0 \\ \end{array} \right)$ and $|D_{off}\rangle = \left( \begin{array}{ccc}
0 \\
 1 \\ \end{array} \right)$

Comment: @ Mark Mitchison: But, since the unitary time evolution operator is defined as an integral of H over time, the, we would start out wraping the $\sigma$ in a delta function that is integrated at least over the duration of the triggering of the detector, fully knowing that the integral of the delta function is equal to 1? Just trying to start from first principals, for my own learning and understanding...

Comment: It's probably more straightforward to choose
$$ \exp\left( -\frac{\mathrm{i}\pi}{2} \sigma^x \otimes \lvert A_x \rangle \langle A_x \rvert \right) $$
where $\sigma^x$ is a [Pauli matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pauli_matrices) equivalent to your [M]. You might find [this identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pauli_matrices#Exponential_of_a_Pauli_vector) useful. However, there are many other choices of Hamiltonian, since you have not fixed the interaction time, for example.

Comment: @David The $\delta(t)$ interaction might give the right unitary, but it doesn't necessarily represent the correct physics. In particular it implies a time-dependent Hamiltonian where some external agent switches the interaction on and off infinitely fast: not very physical. More appropriate would be a time independent Hamiltonian which acts over a time $\tau \sim c/d$, where $c$ is the speed of light and $d$ is the size of the detector. But there are other ways.

Comment: In reality the detector may be strongly coupled to the environment so that the approximation of unitary evolution wouldn't even be valid. So it's probably not worth your time getting too hung up on how to model this right now.